# Conversion: datetime to time

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am working on legacy database in which there is a table having `time` as its data type but In Grails when we define a field of type `Date` then it generates a field of type `datetime`, is there any way to give instruction in domain so that it generate the corresponding column of type `time`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mapping` and `sqlType`

```
class MyClass {
    Date myDate
    static mapping = {
        myDate sqlType: "time"
    }
}
```

Further info [here](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Database%20Mapping/column.html)